# Disabling/Deactivating scripts in the Unity MonoDevelop

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a folder in my Unity's `Assets` directory that contains several scripts with errors and missing directives, etc...

So, I looked for a way of getting Unity to **disregard** all those scripts until I have found the directives and solution...

I found out that in MonoDevelop, I could click on the little `Settings` icon that appears to the right of every script (on the Solution viewpad) and change their setting from `Compile` to `None`, but this still does not **exclude** them from being compiled, so I still get error messages that prevent me from running my Unity app.

Is there another way of doing this, without having to cut that directory out of my Unity project through windows explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know - no, you can not do that: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/excluding-unreferenced-scripts-from-builds.13406/

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a development issue, you can just comment out all the code in those scripts. `Ctrl/Cmd + A`, then `Ctrl/Cmd + /`.